# Avalonia TabControl

Tags: c#, avaloniaui

Desktop application.I want to have a tab with 2 items : sent and inbox , for my email system app.So after a little research on Avalonia's built-in controls, I found TabControl to be the most suited one.XAML:

```
<TabControl Width="150"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Background="Gray"
            TabStripPlacement="Left">
    
    <TabItem Header="Inbox">
    </TabItem>
    
    <TabItem Header="Sent">
    </TabItem>
    
</TabControl>
```

which looks good for now:[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRQsz.png)

I want the remaining white space to be used to show either the sent or the received emails.So I thought of using the tabitem's **content** property.To my surprise, instead of displaying the content in the white remaining zone, it does this:

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mH7LG.png)

XAML:

```
    <TabControl Width="150"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Background="Gray"
                TabStripPlacement="Left">
        
        <TabItem Header="Inbox">
            <Button>why</Button>
        </TabItem>
        
        <TabItem Header="Sent">
        </TabItem>
        
    </TabControl>
```

The content I will actually be displaying later will be lists of emails , stacked one on top of another which will all be put in a **UserControl**.But first , I need to figure out how can my content populate the empty remaining space instead of the actual bar space.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the width of the TabControl to 150.  The white space isn't a part of the tab control, it's the left over window space.  All tab item content will display within the tab control.

It seems you want only the ItemsPanel to be 150 width and Gray. To do this we define an ItemsPanelTemplate, which the control will use to create the ItemsPanel.  By default, a tab control will use a WrapPanel as it's template, so we will reproduce the same, but with our modifications.  You can, however, use any Panel and customize it to your liking. This can also be done for any control that derives from ItemsControl (or SelectingItemsControl which derives from ItemsControl), such as ListBoxes and ComboBoxes.

```xml
<TabControl TabStripPlacement="Left">
  <TabControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <WrapPanel Width="150" Background="Gray"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </TabControl.ItemsPanel>

  <TabItem Header="Inbox">
    <Button>That's why</Button>
  </TabItem>

  <TabItem Header="Sent">
  </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```